# Isotope: imagesLoaded not working

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope JS on a site I am working on.  I am using the StraightAcross layout option.  The issue is that all the images start to load and then Isotope kicks in to create the layout.  I am following the documentation and I have implemented both methods:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin

My code:

```
 var $container = $('#container');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('#container').isotope({ 
        layoutMode : 'straightAcross'
        });
    });
```

I have also tried:

```
$(window).load(function() {
            $('#container').isotope({ 
            layoutMode : 'straightAcross'
    });
```

And

```
$(window).load(function() {
     var $container = $('#container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $('#container').isotope({ 
            layoutMode : 'straightAcross'
            });
        });
    });
```

Since I m using a straight across layout the jump is pretty jarring. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT
Added dev link:

```
http://66.214.147.58/tracey_dev/
```

EDIT 2

I have made a video of the issue.

http://vimeo.com/50708647

At the beginning, the images, which are larger than the container, start to load stacked one on top of each other.  Once they load then Isotope kicks in and creates the layout, resizing the images to the container and arranging them horizontal.

Since this site is going to be resizable, the images are saved in a larger format to maintain quality.  I updated the images to load large images from a server.

I would like the images not to show until the Isotope script kicks in.

Edit 3

Ok, I think I understand what imagesLoaded does.  It doesnt pre-load the images and hide them until its done, then trigger Isotope, which is what I was under the impression it does.  What I did to get around my issue is add hide() on document ready and then a show() on window.load.  This is not solving my issue of file size and loading (ill solve that as I go along), but it solved my issue with the jump.  Thanks again for your input.  Here is my code that works.

```
<!-- Hides the container for loading -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#container').hide();
});
</script>

<!-- Isotope Script -->
<script>

$(window).load(function() {
    // set panels equal to window size
    setSectionSize();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        setSectionSize();
    });

     // function to set panels to window size
    function setSectionSize(){
        var windowHeight = $(window).height()-170;

        //resize section containing image
        $('#container').css({'height':windowHeight+'px'});         
        };

        /* Load Isotope */
        var $container = $('#container');

        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.show();
        $container.isotope({ 
        layoutMode : 'straightAcross'

        });
         });
                 });
</script>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Which "jump" is jarring? One can't see it, because you did not link to your jsfiddle, jsbin or online development sandbox where one could see and examine what's going on. Help SO users to help you.

Comment: In Google Chrome, nothing "jumps". If you open the Network panel in Chrome's devtools, you see what loads when and what can't load. Have you tried without your webfont (bad webfont implementations can get in the way)? If you're using imagesLoaded - why then do you use the Lazy Load plugin to delay your loading of images? Also, you're using an image with 1600px × 916px which the browser has to scale down to 969px × 555px (for my browser window size) which is not good practice, see http://www.petapixel.com/2009/11/12/why-you-should-never-let-browsers-resize-your-photos/

Comment: Thanks for your input Systembolaget.  I updated my post with a video showing the issue (on Chorome, Safari and Firefox). I removed the web font.  I was using LazyLoad but wasn't implemented, so it wasn't loading.  I would like to still use it. as far as large images, the site is resizable, so the images must be large in order to maintain quality.  I was thinking of implementing some sort of image resize script (http://adaptive-images.com) but it seems that its based on screen resolution which would not work with the size scrolling method well. Thank you again.

Comment: If you include gigantic images like this directly, rather than making them available for viewers via a "view full size" option or similar, you won't get around abnormal loading times and a long wait until images can be rendered to the viewer's screen. All that image data needs to be fetched first and, since Isotope needs width and height of elements to layout correctly, the viewer will experience a blank screen for a long time, if you, for example, hide the container untill all images are loaded. Test your site with https://www.pingdom.com/ or similar to examine performance and image loading.